# Redirect using .htaccess file. How?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file as "documentRoot/app/webroot/myFile.php"

I need to be able to access this file at "mySite/myFile.xml" ie when i type myFile.xml a call should goto "documentRoot/app/webroot/myFile.php"

How can i do this by using .htaccess file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml$ documentRoot/app/webroot/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: is `Options +FollowSymlinks` necessary?

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect 301 /mySite/myFile.xml http://example.com/documentRoot/app/webroot/myFile.php
```